Docker not reading API key in .env file
Description
I am trying to deploy my Flask web app to Google Cloud Run, but the Docker is not reading the .env file that contains the API key. The following image is my project directory. (requirements.txt containing python-dotenv package is just below the readMe.md)

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.11-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app

docker-compose.yml
services:
  flask_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.action
    environment:
      - API_KEY=${API_KEY}

I have almost zero experience in Docker so I'm not sure if I have configured the above files right. I would be grateful for your guidance to solve this issue.

I would recommend setting this with https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/environment-variables, instead of committing an API key to your container and adding an extra dependency.

You need to ensure that your requirements.txt file has python-dotenv package. So that you should be able to read .env files. Hence add python-dotenv into your requirments.txt file.
Secondly make .env file and use COPY Command to copy it in your Dockerfile (Although this will be unsafe way of doing things... Can be done for Testing purpose).
COPY .env .env

For Production Environment:
It is recommended to us Google Cloud Run -> (Your Service Name ) -> Edit & Deploy New Revision -> Environment variables
You can go there and define your API_Key over there and deploy it in cloud run it will be able to pick it up.

requirements.txt containing python-dotenv package is just below the readMe.md!
Seems like I've missed that to mention it in the post.

Just to clarify, do you mean I should paste COPY .env .env to my Dockerfile?

Yes Please, it is required to copy. Put this in your Dockerfile

Copying the .env into the image means you would have secrets included inside your image that anyone with access to the image could read. Do not do that. If you already did, consider those API keys compromised.

Yes, Its best to use Cloud Run Environment Variables or Google Secret Manager for production. For Testing or Dev he can push it.
